# Where, if anywhere, can I find the version of vectorian176.pgf, used to compile pgfornament's manual?

Tags: errors, packages, pgfornament

Is there a corrected version of `vectorian176.pgf` around somewhere? As it is shown in `pgfornament`'s manual, I guess there should be, but the one in TL 2018 gives an error.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian
176.pgf
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.105 }
        def
?
```

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}
  \pgfornament{176}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know but there seems to be just an unmatched `}` at the end. When I remove it, there is no error, and a nice (?) ornament.

Comment: By induction one can prove that the `def` can also be dropped. Induction works as follows. There is no `def` in `vectorian
175.pgf`, so it is also not needed in `vectorian
176.pgf`. And to confirm this, I did `grep def /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfornament/vectorian/vectorian*.pgf`, which only found a match in `vectorian176.pgf`. ;-)

Comment: Hmm .... Odd, isn't it?

Comment: 176 is even but the extra `} def` is odd. ;-)

Comment: Error when I translate the code from eps to pgf.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because has been fixed by package update